# Are Sony Vaio S series or T series laptops  compatible with both windows 7 and Ubuntu 12.04 in dual-boot installation

Tags: dual-boot, windows-7, vaio

I am planning to buy a new laptop which is suitable for both Ubuntu 12.04 and windows 7 in dual boot configuration.

I am looking for **Sony Vaio** two models with configurations:

1. 13.3" S series Customizable laptop ( SVS131190S)
   3rd gen Intel® Core™ i5-3210M processor (2.50GHz / 3.10GHz with Turbo Boost)
   Intel® HD Graphics 4000
   4GB (4GB fixed onboard + 1 open slot) DDR3-1333Mhz
   500GB (5400rpm) hard drive
2. 13.3" T series Customizable ultrabook
   3rd gen Intel® Core™ i7-3517U processor (1.90GHz / 3.00GHz with Turbo Boost)
   Intel® HD Graphics 4000
   500GB (5400rpm) + 32GB MLC hybrid hard drive with RAID 0
   6GB (4GB fixed onboard + 2GB removable) DDR3-1333Mhz

Can anyone please tell me which laptop will function better for dual booting?

Any help/comments are really appreciated.

Comment: I was trying ubuntu 12.04 USB on vaio T13 (French) at sony store Paris, but wifi don't work. The wifi wifi light is green, but in fact you can't check wireless in ubuntu menu and you can't see any network (SSID). I was trying on two model of vaio T13 (but not i5-3210M, perhaps a i5-2567).
On vaio S serie I haven't problems, wifi works perfectly.

Comment: With the new Ubuntu 12.04.1 wifi work correctly. But I can install ubuntu on my sony T13 ... Have you a tuto to install ubuntu in native mode on Sony T13 ?

Answer (score 3):

Wifi problem seems to be quick to solve - in terminal execute command:

```
sudo rmmod acer_wmi
```

and instantly all the wifi networks are accessible. It turns out to be an Ubuntu problem:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/938630

Answer (score 0):

They should be alright. I'm getting a Dell, and I'm assuming since it's said to be one of the most UbuntuxWindows-boot-friendly computers, I'm fairly happy. But, saying this, it should be OK for both your VAIO(s) because it's an OS, and most computers built after something like 1995 should be able to dual boot fine.

As for which computer, personally I would go for the 13.3" T series Customizable, because it has an i7 processor which will be quicker on both systems, plus 6GB of RAM, which is great for dual booting (if you do get Ubuntu on this one, I recommend the x64 version, if that is what your computer can handle.)

But overall, both should be OK, but I recommend the second one if it's not out of your budget.